# Converting Vector Valued Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble turning this vector function into something like a $y=mx +b$ equation.

$$r(t) = 2cos(t)^3 \hat{i} + 2sin(t)^3 \hat{j}$$

Normally I would say $x = 2cos(t)^3$ and $y=2sin(t)^3$ and either rearrange and solve x for t or use trigonometric identities to simplify things. But I don't see what can be done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clues:

$\sin(t)^2 + \cos(t)^2 = 1$

Comment: I can see how that would help with a u substitution with integrating, but I can't find anything with that.

Comment: @bh3244:  $y^{2/3}+x^{2/3}=2^{2/3}$